# How to set custom font to android toolbar's subtitle?

Tags: android, fonts, toolbar, subtitle

i want to get the subtitle´s textview in an android's toolbar to change it's font. Actually i'm doing it with the title, getting it on this way:

```
Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
f.setAccessible(true);
titleTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);
```

I've tried with the same code but trying to get "mSubtitleTextView" but that's not the solution.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try it with a TypeFace

Comment: That is what i'm trying, but i need the textview

Comment: Where's the title, in the actionbar?

Comment: I get it with the code above

Comment: So now you want to change he font of titleTextView?

Comment: Im showing how i do the same for the title. I want to do it with the subtitle

Answer (score 5):

You can get the subtitle TextView like this:

```
View subTitleView = toolbar.getChildAt(1);
```

If you don't add any views to the toolbar, his default structure is:

```
[0] - (TextView) title
[1] - (TextView) subtitle
[2] - (ActionMenuView) menu
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the best way, but in a pinch this will work. You will have to figure out a way to implement `myTypefaceSpan` though; I'm using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) so it ties together decently for me.

```
CalligraphyTypefaceSpan myTypefaceSpan = new CalligraphyTypefaceSpan(
    TypefaceUtils.load(this.getAssets(), "fonts/custom_font.ttf"));

public static void setToolbarSubtitle(String subtitle, Context context) {
    SpannableStringBuilder sBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    sBuilder.append(subtitle);
    sBuilder.setSpan(MainActivity.myTypefaceSpan, 0, sBuilder.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ((MainActivity)context).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(sBuilder);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working with the title, are you doing with reflection as well?